# Creating sympy Matrices from columns

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I'm trying to create a sympy Matrix by choosing columns from an existing Matrix (for calculating principal minors). At the moment I'm doing it like this:

```
>>> A = Matrix(3,5,[2,3,4,1,34,23,12,54,5,0,0,0,3,4,5])
>>> l = [A[:,i].T for i in [2,3,0]]
>>> M = Matrix(l).T
>>> M
Matrix([
[ 4, 1,  2],
[54, 5, 23],
[ 3, 4,  0]])
```

But this seems wasteful to me (especially the need to transpose twice. I don't know if this is time consuming). Is there a better way? Would there be a better way if i only need the determinant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[2, 3, 0]` as index.

```
>>> A = Matrix(3, 5, [2,3,4,1,34,23,12,54,5,0,0,0,3,4,5])
>>> A[:, [2,3,0]]
Matrix([
[ 4, 1,  2],
[54, 5, 23],
[ 3, 4,  0]])
```

---

For lower version that does not support using list as a index, you can use [`Matrix.hstack`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixBase.hstack):

```
>>> Matrix.hstack(*(A.col(i) for i in [2,3,0]))
Matrix([
[ 4, 1,  2],
[54, 5, 23],
[ 3, 4,  0]])
```

or `Matrix.row_join`:

```
>>> # from functools import reduce  # For Python 3.x
>>> reduce(Matrix.row_join, (A.col(i) for i in [2,3,0]), Matrix(3,0,[]))
Matrix([
[ 4, 1,  2],
[54, 5, 23],
[ 3, 4,  0]])
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I get an IndexError: Invalid index a[[2, 3, 0]]. Do I have a wrong version (0.7.4.1)? or is this only possible with numpy matrices?

Comment: @pyrogen, I used `sympy 1.0`

Comment: @pyrogen, I updated the answer to include alternative approaches. (tested with sympy 0.7.4.1)